# How to get rows from table as json array list format in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows information from table in MySQL. Rather than getting as it is, I want to get this information as JSON array list type.

For example,

```
A   B   C
=========
1   2   3 
2   3   4
```

I want it to become data like the followings.

```
{ rows: [ 
            { "A" :  1, "B" : 2, "C" : 3}, 
            { "A" :  2, "B" : 3, "C" : 4}
]}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this in application code?

Comment: @Strawberry I thought this function may be provided by MySQL itself and it is gonna be good function whenever I want to test REST APIs with json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can achieve as below:

```
SELECT CONCAT('{ rows:[', result, ']}') AS result1 FROM
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('{', jsondata, '}' SEPARATOR ',') AS result FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CONCAT
    (
      '"A":'   , A  , ',' 
      '"B":', B, ','
      '"C":'  , C
    ) AS jsondata
  FROM test
) AS jsondata
) AS jsonsdata1;
```

SQL Demo link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95bbbc/2

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code and help. Is this only way to do this? In this way, I should write every columns and data by myself. I have many tables with tons of columns.

Comment: You can also convert this at the server side like C#, PHP. It would be easy